# Automatically switch between 2 Air Conditioning sources?

Tags: ac

In my head I have a RV application in which an air conditioning unit would draw from shore power if available, but if disconnected the Air conditioner should draw from the battery.

Obviously this could be solved by using an inverter/charger hybrid to just pass the current through, but I'm wondering if there's something cheap I could buy to conditionally connect a single load to two AC sources.

Comment: Google automatic transfer switch (ATS). This is the component inside the inverter that performs the switchover.

Comment: Yes, the power utilities **REQUIRE** that a DPDT contactor be installed or built into the backup system. This prevents "back-feed", in which UPS or generator power is accidentally sent back into the AC line. This is worse than a short circuit. Things go BOOM! A then you get a repair bill from the utility company for any damages caused.

Comment: *"connect a single load to two AC sources"*??? Is this what you want?

Comment: If "cheap" is important to you, the $100 transfer switch is not the problem, the problem will be the inverter and batteries sized large enough to run your AC for any significant length of time.